# How to eliminate odors from the vents?

Tags: ac, smell, vents

How to eliminate odors from the vents? (The odor is noticeable, even though it's been months since I used the A/C)

Many people recommend spraying Lysol Disinfectant Spray into the A/C air intake, while running the air intake for a few minutes.

However, Lysol Disinfectant Spray is flammable and possibly corrosive.

Is this something I should try doing on my own? If not, who can do it, and what's this type of service called?

Comment: Welcome to SE.  This is a dupe and I think the mapped to responses will be helpful to you.  Cheers and thanks for the contribution.

Comment: @DucatiKiller I don't think it's duplicate, because the odors (in my question) are not correlated with A/C usage. Also, my question is "how to fix it" rather than the why, which is presumably the mold growth.

Comment: The first response in the other question I mapped to has solutions for resolution.  If you need to understand howto fix it from a dissassembly perspective perhaps include that in your question.  It will differentiate it from the question I mapped to.